Django app under nginx and django gives a 502 sporadically on a large HTML page, other errors also
Before I did anything I would see a bad gateway on my deployed site or the error referenced here:
Django/nginx/gunicorn giving this in deployment: GET https://.../ net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)
I changed a few things in nginx.conf and see less of the incomplete chunked error but still get the bad gateway.  Viewing the nginx error.log I noticed errors that make no sense to me when I get the 502 bad gateway:
2024/09/16 12:34:24 [crit] 25088#0: *103 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/4/01/0000000014" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 10.75.0.152, server: 10.75.1.214, request: "GET /mainpage/nicfips/nicfipsguide/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/apo_web.sock:/mainpage/nicfips/nicfipsguide/", host: "10.75.0.204:8080”

I checked the folder where this referenced page exists and it is the same users as other links and and has what should be the correct chmod on it as well.    As a test I took the HTML that is displayed on the page in question and it runs everytime so I know it is a timing issue of sorts, there is. just a REALLY long HTML page (I could break it up) but I am not sure why simple HTML is causing issues this day in age.  The page does no database queries or anything.
Guessing I need to edit a timing in a config file somewhere just not sure what or where.  Also for reference the HTML trying to be rendered is 1160 lines long.
EDIT: Tofix the chunk error I did implement from that link was changing:
in nginx.conf "sendfile off;" (from on to off), I do still get that chunk error on pages that are REALLY long now.  So not even sure this really did anything?

"Permission denied" line is quite a hint. Check out /var/lib/nginx content permissions. I suspect you're hit by question I'm linking in my VTC.

That was it, I had even referenced that elsewhere.  Ty, I fixed it by setting the proxy_temp_path /tmp/nginx 1 2;
